# Hosting multiple meteor apps on one server

Tags: meteor, nginx

I have 2 meteor apps running on one Ubuntu server on DO. I have also set up nginx for "servering"

Config files:

sailsadria.conf : http://pastebin.com/eCicpNxK
ytp.klancir.work.conf : http://pastebin.com/cNKtA0dV

Now...

http://sailsadria.com/ which is on port 3000 works smoothly as expected while http://ytp.klancir.work/  goes on ngnix root. On the other hand http://ytp.klancir.work:3010 goes to the right app that is working on that port (but I suppose that any URL or the IP i forward with the appended port will end up on the right location)

Symlinks are also set up

The domains are configured:
sailsadria: http://screencast.com/t/iqKUlQlDgj8
ytp.klancir.work: http://screencast.com/t/DJJdLfqna

I dont know how to set up that http://ytp.klancir.work/ goes directly to port 3010 in other words - directly to the app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOLUTION: sudo service nginx restart....

Comment: Yup, most probably you edited your config files and forgot to restart the service.